# Based on a bitmap input file , show three other bitmap images showing separately the three color components

Tags: c#

Well I have basic knowledge of C#, but I have medium c++ skills. Someone asked me to help them at an assignement and after I consulted the Internet , I thought i managed to do it but I don't know why it doesn't work . The assignement : Write a program to generate, based on a bitmap file input, three  bitmap files , showing separately the three color components.
The code :

```
    private void GetPixel_1(PaintEventArgs e)
    {


        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Image);
        Bitmap bmp2 = new Bitmap(pictureBox3.Image);
        Bitmap bmp3 = new Bitmap(pictureBox4.Image);
        Color color = new Color();
        for (int ii = 0; ii < 200; ii++)
        {
            for (int jj = 0; jj < 200; jj++)
            {
                color = bmp.GetPixel(ii, jj);
                bmp1.SetPixel(ii, jj, Color.FromArgb(color.R, 0, 0));
                bmp2.SetPixel(ii, jj, Color.FromArgb(0, 0,color.B));
                bmp3.SetPixel(ii, jj, Color.FromArgb(0, color.G, 0));

            }
        }
        pictureBox2.Image = bmp1;
        pictureBox3.Image = bmp2;
        pictureBox4.Image = bmp3;



    }
```

I know this might look basic for most but still I would be gratefull if someone could help me.

Comment: What doesn't work? Any errors?

Comment: Is pictureBox2.Image empty before creating the bitmaps ? Or a copy of the original ?

Comment: No errors. pictureBox2,3,4 are empty and pictureBox1 has an image.

Comment: I just thought about this, but might it be because the image in pictureBox1 I put it from the Visual part and not trought code?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("Image.bmp");
        Bitmap red = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        Bitmap blue = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
        Bitmap green = new Bitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

        for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
            {
                Color c = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);
                red.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(c.R, 0, 0));
                blue.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, 0, c.B));
                green.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(0, c.G, 0));
            }
        }

        // - Don't forget to save, until now we're only messing with the loaded memory of the bitmap.
        red.Save("Red.bmp");
        blue.Save("Blue.bmp");
        green.Save("Green.bmp");
    }        
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I tried it and I guess it works, but could you tell me where the location of the Image.bmp should be =D? I kinda tried everywhere and can't seem to load it.

Comment: @MisteryKei For the image you must either pass the entire filePath (`C:\MyProject\Image.bmp`) or it must be in the folder where the application is running on, for example, `\YourProject\bin\Debug\MyConsole.exe` (or the Release folder if you're building it as Release). Also note that if the code is in a class library, the important is where the **application** is (the executable code).

Comment: Ahh .. thank you very much , it works just as it needed it . ^^

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the bitmaps, otherwise if some of this code ends up in a loop you'll end up with an out of memory error.